# Python not installing

Tags: 16.04, python

I did sudo apt-get install python-pip, but it always stops at

> Reading package lists... 55%

What is the problem? This is on Ubuntu 16.04, and I am accessing a VM on a cloud service through the terminal on mac.

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you try to update the software first using the command: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` ? If this command runs successfully, try running `sudo apt install python-pip` afterwards.

Comment: It worked, but when I check the version with `python -V`, it still says version 2.7.12. I want 3.5.2+

Comment: Apparently I need python 3.5 to go to python 3.6 or something. I followed the instructions on https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-5-on-ubuntu/ and now I have python 3.5. Thanks for your help though